# React.js Cannot read property '__reactAutoBindMap' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know this has been asked before but the suggested solutions don't help me, so, here's my code which for some reason fails.

app.js:

```
(function(React, _) {
    var App = require('./components/App.react');

_.mixin(_.string.exports());

var render = function() {
    React.render(
        React.createElement(App),
        document.getElementById('reactContent')
    );
};
render();
}(React, _));
```

And then, App.react.js:

```
var React = require('react');
var Test = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    return <div>Hello world</div>
}
})

module.exports = Test;
```

Now, my console says:

```
Warning: This JSX uses a plain function. Only React components are valid in     React's JSX transform.
app.js:20281 Warning: Something is calling a React component directly. Use a     factory or JSX instead. See: http://fb.me/react-legacyfactory
app.js:6475 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactAutoBindMap' of null
```

Feels like the simplest thing... I'll include my package.json just incase it's needed.

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
"gulp": "3.8.10",
"gulp-run": "1.6.5",
"gulp-less": "2.0.1",
"gulp-concat": "2.4.3",
"gulp-uglify": "1.0.2",
"gulp-minify-css": "0.3.11",
"gulp-jshint": "1.9.0",
"browser-sync": "1.8.2",
"browserify": "3.44.2",
"vinyl-source-stream": "1.0.0",
"vinyl-buffer": "1.0.0",
"reactify": "latest",
"underscore": "^1.7.0",
"del": "1.1.1",
"envify": "~3.0.0"
  },
  "paths": {
"less": "assets/less/*.less",
"js": "./app/**/*.js",
"jsx": "./app/**/*.jsx",
"app": "./app/app.js",
"html": "*.html"
  },
  "dest": {
    "style": "style.css",
    "app": "app.js",
    "dist": "dist"
  },
  "dependencies": {
"react": "latest",
"underscore": "^1.7.0",
"flux": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

There's a lot more in here as you can see from the .json file, I just rebuilt the code to make a really simple case and to isolate the issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `React.createFactory(require('./components/App.react'))` as explained here: https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/d7bce729f38730399d28

or use ES6 classes: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html

EDIT:
I found the original Blog Post: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/10/14/introducing-react-elements.html

Comment: Thanks but after a quick glance I saw that this didn't affect me if I was using JSX, which I believe I am, right? Anyway - after putting "var React = require('react')" at the top of app.js, it works fine.

Comment: I think it does since in react.Render you are not using jsx ...oh when it works it work :-)

Comment: I ended up using `App = React.createFactory(require('path/to/App'))`